# s3 presigned url for access to entire folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an s3 bucket that has individual folders that contain different websites. I would like to generate a presigned url for access to a specific folder, however I would like to have the url allow access to all objects in that folder. Is this possible?

I'm using the ruby aws-sdk gem v2.

My existing code looks like this

```
  def get_object_url(bucket_name, object_name)
    res = Aws::S3::Resource::new
    obj = res.bucket(bucket_name).object(object_name)
    exp = 1.day
    obj.presigned_url(
      :get, 
      {
        expires_in: exp,
        virtual_host: true
      }
    )
  end
```

passing the folder name as object_name doesn't work.

Comment: One relatively straightforward workaround would be for your app to accept a request from an user for -- for example -- a path pattern such as `/downloads/secure/${bucket}/${s3_object_path}`.  If the user is authorized for the download, generate a signed URL with a short expiration and return a `302` http redirect with the signed URL in the `Location:` header.  I used this approach to retrofit a legacy platform with downloadable files in S3.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, S3 doesn't really have a true concept of a folder. The folders are "created" using segments of the object paths. They do not exist independently of objects.

Comment: In addition, the signature in both the V2 and V4 algorithm is dependent on the specific object key ("path") and for any given set of request parameters, there can only be exactly one valid signature, making the possibility of a wildcard (which would mean more than one potentially valid signature, object and "folder,") impossible.

Comment: Any news on this? Is this limitation still existing? What could be workarounds for that?

Comment: @user3211074 Yes this limitation still exists. Its unlikely to change due to how S3 is designed.

Answer (score 8):

I recently had this problem and i could find a solution with custom policies for signed URL using cloudfront.

Has some pros and cons, the main one is that u dont need to sign for each object so is much more faster if you need to share many objects. But it goes like outside of aws traffic.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-creating-signed-url-custom-policy.html

Answer (score 5):

My workaround will be to compress files and folder structure into an archive (like zip) and just upload that single object (file) to the presigned URL.

Comment: A surprisingly simple solution :). Espectially good with ZIP, since you can get the dir listing with a range request and any specific member file with another range request, so you don't loose much.